# How to extract tuples from a list of tuples which length could be variable

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples which comes from another part of my Python script and which can have a variable length. I want to extract separately the tuples and store them to multiple new lists.

Here is an example of what I can get:

```
mylist = [
('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'),
('ddd', 'eee', 'fff'),
('ggg', 'hhh', 'iii'),
('jjj', 'kkk', 'lll'), 
... etc.
]
```

And the result I want is this:

```
mylist1 = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
mylist2 = ['ddd', 'eee', 'fff']
mylist3 = ['ggg', 'hhh', 'iii']
mylist4 = ['jjj', 'kkk', 'lll']
etc.
```

Since I'm beginning Python, I know that a `for` loop can extract the items of my list, like this:

```
for item in mylist:
   mylist1 = item
```

But the problem with the code above is that `list1` will only contain the last tuple and the others are not stored anyway. I need to put a loop inside a loop or something like that.

How to do that?

Comment: Why can't you just use `list[0]`, `list[1]`, etc?

Comment: why are you trying to do this?

Comment: @JohnGordon Gordon Because the length of my original list is variable?

Comment: @FrançoiseDionisi so why do you need some arbitrary number of variables?

Comment: @SuperStew Because I need to insert the new lists created from the original list in a email at the end, and I need to split each item for the email to be readable.

Comment: I believe this is an [XY problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). I don't think there's a good way to do this. Please tell us what you were originally trying to do and we can suggest another way to do it.

Comment: @FrançoiseDionisi so why don't you just loop through your original list? why try to turn them all into different variables?

Comment: Now that you've clarified, I can confidently tell you that defining these variables won't help you accomplish that goal.

Comment: @SuperStew What do you mean by "just loop through your original list"?

Comment: @FrançoiseDionisi I mean instead of a loop to make new variables, use the loop to attach it to an email or whatever you need to do.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon I want to use the tuples as line of text inside a email. I cannot put my code here as it is 200 lines long. So I give you a more readable example.

Comment: @FrançoiseDionisi so why not something like `for x in mainlist: emailtext + str(x)`? also don't call lists 'list'

Comment: @FrançoiseDionisi - you have 2 ways to solve this [XY_problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), by append to new list like my answer below (convert each tuple and append to new list), or if you still want to give anew seperated list object with special name for each tuple, the only way i know is to append it as class attributes in run time with the method `setattribute(list)`

Comment: I don't expect you to post all 200 lines. I'm just saying that defining an arbitrary number of variables is not a good way to go about adding them to an email.

Comment: Alright all. I understand this is a complex way to do what I want. I will search for another method. Thanks for thinking about my problem anyway.

Comment: Did none of the answers help you? In any case, it might help to spend more time learning how to use loops.

Comment: There’s always the evil ‘eval’ function...

Answer (score 2):

In your question, you said,

> the problem with the code above is that list1 will only contain the last tuple and the others are not stored anyway

That's not quite true, though. It is true after the list finishes, but, while the loop is still running, list1 will be set to each item of the list in sequence. Therefore, if you add list1 to your email within the loop, each item of the list will be added.

I would do something like this:

```
for item in your_list:
   email += list(item)
   email += '\n'
```

Or, more simply:

```
email += '\n'.join(map(list, your_list))
```

Answer (score 1):

append each inner tuple to new list. so your final list become a list of lists:

```
[['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'], [['ddd', 'eee', 'fff'],....]
```

```
fin_list = []

original_list = [
('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'),
('ddd', 'eee', 'fff'),
('ggg', 'hhh', 'iii'),
('jjj', 'kkk', 'lll'), 
.......
]


for each_tuple in original_list:
    fin_list .append(list(each_tuple))
```

Output:

```
[['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'], ['ddd', 'eee', 'fff'], ['ggg', 'hhh', 'iii'], ['jjj', 'kkk', 'lll']]
```

**APPROACH 2**

```
class XY_Lists(object):
  def __init__(self,list_of_tups):
    count=0
    for each_tup in list_of_tups:
      setattr(self,"List_{}".format(count),list(each_tup))
      count+=1

my_named_list=XY_Lists(original_list)
print(my_named_list.List_0)
# you can keep accessing the class object attributes one by one
```

output:

```
['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
```

Comment: this isn't what OP is asking for, I don' think

Comment: this is the only way you can answer this question. we have variable list length. do you know a better way to do this?

Comment: No, but he doesn't seem to be asking how to turn tuples into lists. He was trying to define a variable for each sublist. Which is why all the comments trying to clarify. If this is actually his end goal, I guess he'll see it.

Comment: @SuperStew - how you can do this in run time? maybe i can think about special class, that can append variables  attributes as lists with `setattribute`

Comment: yea there's not an easy way to do. certainly not a straightforward way. the class thing is probably your best shot for it, but it'd be a pain

Comment: leave comment please if you think i need to fix my answer.

Comment: I will try that too. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness' sake, here is the answer to the original question:

```
mylist = [
('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'),
('ddd', 'eee', 'fff'),
('ggg', 'hhh', 'iii'),
('jjj', 'kkk', 'lll'), 
]

for i in range(len(mylist)):
    exec(f"list{i+1} = list(mylist[{i}])")
```

However as the discussion makes clear, this is not a good idea and there is certainly a simpler way of achieving what you want to do. The code above will create a bunch of variables in memory which are not explicitly defined in the code, so will certainly cause headaches when it comes to debugging and maintaining the code in future.

Comment: Thank you. I understand that my idea is a wobbly solution to do what I want at the end. I will try to rethink it.

Answer (score 0):

> Although this code would not be able to dynamically allocate the tuples into variables, but it can extract the tuples from the given list and convert them into list through "List comprehension". Please let me know if dynamic allocation would be possible.

```
Mylist = [('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'), ('ddd', 'eee', 'fff'), ('ggg', 'hhh', 'iii'), ('jjj', 'kkk', 'lll')]

for i in range(len(Mylist)):
   print("Mylist",i+1,"=",[x for x in Mylist[i]])
```